# How this AWK program works?

Tags: awk

Input data:

```
2018 Fiat 125
2018-01-17: Opel 2 Volvo 3
2017-01-21: Fiat 5 Fiat 6
2017-02-22: Opel 7 Fiat 8
2018-01-31: Fiat 9 Opel 17
```

Code:

```
$1 !~ /17/ {t[$2]+= $3;}
END {for (i in t)
print i": "t[i];}
```

The result is:
Fiat: 134

I understand that the condition  !~ /17/  is fulfilled only for the first and last line because there is no 17. But what does the program do next?
There is an instruction:

```
{t[$2]+= $3;}
```

So (as  $2 is Fiat and $3 is 125): t[Fiat]= t[Fiat] + 125 ?

I assume that 134 is the sum of 125 and 9.
What is "i" ?

Comment: correction: *`no 17`* should be *`no 17 in the 1st field`*; `t[$2]` uses 2nd field (eg, `Fiat`) as array index; `+= $3` adds the value from 3rd field to the value currently stored in the array so for the 2 matching rows ... `t[Fiat]=0+125=125` and then `t[Fiat]=125+9=134`

Comment: And why i is Fiat in the last line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$1 !~ /17/ {t[$2]+= $3;}
```

When the first column (`$1`) **does NOT contains** `17`, because of the `!~`, then add the value to an array `t[$2]+=$3`. For the first line this is `t['Fiat']+=125`.  Then `+=` adds the value to the previous value of `t['Fiat']`

```
END {for (i in t)
print i": "t[i];}
```

When done (in the `END`), print all values of this array.

This can be seen/debugged when changing the script to:

```
$1 !~ /17/ {
        t[$2]+= $3;
        print "for",$2," the count is updated with ",$3," to: ",t[$2]," in the line: ",$0
}
END {for (i in t)
print i": "t[i];}
```

The array does contain (can contain, because in this example it's just 1 value) multiple value. The `for (i in t) { .... }` loops over the contents of the array.

This can be tested using: `awk '{ t[$2]+=$3; }END{ for (i in t) { print i":"t[i]; }}' input.txt`, which will output:

```
Fiat:139
Opel:9
```

which with this data, outputs:

```
for Fiat  the count is updated with  125  to:  125  in the line:  2018 Fiat 125
for Fiat  the count is updated with  9  to:  134  in the line:  2018-01-31: Fiat 9 Opel 17
Fiat: 134
```

Comment: And what is "i"?

Comment: Added info about the `for()` loop.